# Date Calculating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can u give me a simple function in vb.net which can take number of days and date as parameters and subtract these number of days from given date.
Forexample

```
Private function Calculate(Byval p_number_days,p_date) as date

 Dim calculated_date as Date= (p_date) - (p_number_days) 
 return calculated


End Function
```

Comment: is it really worth writing a function for this?  it just seems like code bloat.  why not just do mydate.AddDays(0 - days) in the calling code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Function Calculate(ByVal p_Number_Days As Integer, ByVal p_Date As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return p_Date.AddDays(p_Number_Days * -1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the AddDays() method of the DateTime class - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

It can take a negative value as well as positive.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to excuse me, I haven't used VB in a long time, so some syntax might be wrong.

```
Private Function Calculate(p_days AS Integer, p_date AS Date) AS Date
  Return p_date - TimeSpan.FromDays(p_days)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, always represent number of days as a TimeSpan. It makes the code look much nicer.

```
Private function Calculate(Byval p_number_days as TimeSpan,p_date as Date) as date
    Return p_date - p_number_days
```